# How to use Hierarchy Viewer now in android studio 2021?

Tags: android, android-studio

Earlier we can use hierarchy-viewer for "Activities Stack".
Not Layout Inspactor but like in
adb shell dumpsys activity

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer#start

Answer (score 1):

The Alternate is clearly mentioned in Docs .

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer

> Hierarchy Viewer is deprecated. If you're using Android Studio 3.1 or later, you should instead use [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) to inspect your app's view hierarchy at runtime. To profile the rendering speed of your app's layout, use [Window.OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener).